# is it a bad practice to use instance variable in helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

I've been refactoring an old project, and I'm seeing some helper methods difficult to test, because of existence of instance variables inside helpers.

What is the best practice to achieve this? pass these instance variables to the helpers as parameters...

in the test I can do things like this, but it seems quite weird

```
  it 'returns family and categoy names' do
    @category = instance_double(Category, name: 'category_name')
    expect(helper.meta_description_home_products).to eq(
      'blabla - categoria'
    )
  end
```

As an example of controller view and helper:

```
class HomeController < BaseController
  @family = ...
  @category = ...
  @products = ...
end
```

and in views

```
<% @products.each ...
  ...
  my_helper
...
```

and in helpers:

```
  module ApplicationHelper
   def my_helper
     ...
     desctiption = 'blabla' if @category.name == 'blabla'
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if a bad practice, but in that case, it makes your helper know too much about the place where it's going to be used. It depends on a `@category` instance variable, which at the same is an object that must respond to `name`, what if it doesn't? Things like that make your code difficult to move and/or test.

Comment: If it's hard to test then it probably is not a good code. I would just use a `category` parameter, easier to test, easier to understand, easier to use, no magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do it. It tightly couples your controller and view layer making future features, rewrite, and refactoring hard.

It also makes reading, testing and bug fixing both your controller and your view hard.

Separation of concern and responsibility are something to consider. Keeping those do help on long lived projects.